# Fixed sidebar - sticky to footer using jQuery

Tags: jquery, css

I have the following  [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/TGw7j/5/) to demonstrate a page layout I'm working with but am having a hard time achieving what I want.

If you scroll the main content all the way to the bottom, you will see the bottom of the sidebar meet the top of the footer.  *That is  how is should always look* . However, if you resize or scroll you will see that it is not so.

After several days of css fiddlings I concluded this can only be done with js. Please provide a working fiddle, **especially** if you claim it can be done using only CSS as others have in my other question which I was unable to get any of the answers to work. The problem with all the answers proposed is `position:fixed` is removed and the sidebar scrolls with the main content, this is not supposed to happen.

Please help achieve the desired effect

Comment: Sorry I didn't understand, you want the sidebar to have 100% height or the footer to be fixed at the bottom?

Comment: The footer should not be fixed, it should scroll with the main content (purple) and always stick to the bottom of it irrespective of the height of the main content (position:relative). The fixed sidebar should then take 100% of the height under the header when the footer is not in sight. Once you scroll down and the footer becomes visible the sidebar should then take up all remaining height between the header and footer. Further explanation in comment below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPDATE:

This apparently cannot be achieved on CSS only, here's a jQuery solution.

```
var vh = $("body").height() - $("footer").height();
var sh = $("#side").height();

$(window).resize(function() {
    vh = $("body").height() - $("footer").height();
    sh = $("#side").height();
});

$(document).scroll(function() {
    var vs = $(document).scrollTop() + sh + $("footer").height();

    if(vs < vh)
        $("#side").css("bottom", "0px");
    else
        $("#side").css("bottom", (vs - vh) + "px");
});
```

Here's a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/goffreder/cYAct/6/) for testing.

Comment: Hey thanks for trying but this isn't what I want. The footer should not be fixed like in your example. The footer should be position:relative so that it scrolls with the main content (purple) meanwhile the bottom of the fixed sidebar sticks to the top of the footer (like in your example). Here look at this: http://jsfiddle.net/UUFLX/1/ I set the footer back to relative and set the background of body tag a darker shade of green. The sidebar should always cover that darker green area but when you scroll up the footer gets out the way.

Comment: Mh, ok now I get it. And I think you're right, this cannot be achieved  with css only, because you basically need to resize the `#size` div depending on how much of the page you have scrolled down. I made a jsFiddle with a jQuery solution (but it can be easily changed for javascript only), just to see if I got it right: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/goffreder/cYAct/2/). I'll fiddle a little bit more...

Comment: Sorry, I made a bit mistake in the previous fiddle, [THIS](http://jsfiddle.net/goffreder/cYAct/4/) is the good one...

Comment: @goffreder Hi! This is my version based on yours. It's pretty much the same. http://jsfiddle.net/cYAct/5/

Comment: Thank you for the fiddles. Basically you got the functionality right but it needs to take window resize into account. It works perfect under 0-zoom (Ctrl+0) but when zooming out the sidebar extends beyond the footer and when zooming in (then scrolling down, you'll see the darker green protruding again due to sidebar not taking full height. I tried to simply run the jquery on scroll and resize but that's not working it needs something more. Thanks for the help, almost solved

Comment: You just need to recalculate the sizes (in my fiddle, `vh` and `sh`), since they are changed the calculation done in the `scroll` event handler isn't valid anymore. I'll edit the answer with these updates...

Comment: That didnt fix but what did was stripping out the scroll callback function and calling it after the recalculation. Thanks!